# Excel PDF Export -- Hyperlink open in new tab

Tags: excel, pdf, hyperlink

I have been working on something since March. The idea (which works) is that I export pupil timetable from our MIS to excel. I then run it against a file which contains links to pupils Google Classroom hyperlinks and that adds the links to the relevant classes on their timetable. I then do some formatting and export them as individual PDF. All of this happens in VBA.

My question is, can I make it that when a pupil clicks a link on their pdf timetable that it opens in a new tab rather than in the current tab and loses their timetable?

This is the code that creates the hyperlink from the list of classes.

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rFind, Address:=r.Offset(, 1).Value, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:=r.Offset(, 1).Text, TextToDisplay:=r.Value
```

**rFind** is the classname.
**r.Offset** is the url.
**r** is the classname in the range the code is searching through.

I realise this may not be enough information so if you need more just ask. I was hoping there was a simple line of code I could add.
Thanks

Comment: Target=_blank is what you're looking for, I think. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Hyperlinks.Add. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I tried that with various combinations of quotes, no quotes, underscore, no underscore. No joy.